# WPF visual refresh

Tags: c#, wpf, opengl, winforms-interop

I have a UserControl OGLUC that computes visualisation stuff via a `RefreshVisual()` function. (In details it integrates a WinForms C++/CLI class that display an OpenGL window but I don't think that is important).

Visual updates are made at about 10Hz from an external Thread.

```
private void mythread(object o)
{
    OGLUC myogluc= (OGLUC)o;
    while(...)
    {
        Sleep(...); // ensure 10Hz
        myogluc.RefreshVisual();
    }
}

private void Button_Click(...)
{
    // OGLUC MyOGLUC created in XAML
    new Thread(mythread).Start(MyOGLUC); 
}
```

But it does not redraw ... well actually it redraws if I move the mouse over it ...

If I encapsulate the call to RefreshVisual in `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` it works, but ... the function is so heavy that the whole UI will freeze.
I tried different thinks like this :

```
myogluc.RefreshVisual();

myogluc.InvalidateVisual();
myogluc.UpdateLayout();
// or :
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>
   {
      myogluc.InvalidateVisual();
      myogluc.UpdateLayout();
   }));
// or again :
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(()=>
   {
      myogluc.InvalidateVisual();
      myogluc.UpdateLayout();
   }));
```

But it still does not refresh ...

I plan to launch MoveMouse Event as the refresh works if I move the mouse over ... but this is very ugly, hu !? :)

Any suggestion ?

EDIT :

Tried this just now, within, or not, Dispatcher.Invoke and Dispactcher.BeginInvoke ... with no more success :

```
public partial class OGLUC : UserControl
{
...
private void RefreshVisual()
{
    // ... heavy opengl stuff via C++/CLI ...

    // refresh view
    //Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Send, new Action(()=>{
    //Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Send, new Action(()=>{
        winformsPanel.Invalidate(); // the winforms panel
        winformsPanel.Update();
        winformsHost.InvalidateVisual(); // the host for winforms panel
        winformsHost.UpdateLayout();
        InvalidateVisual(); // the OGLUC UserControl
        UpdateLayout();
    //}));
}
}
```

EDIT 2 :
This is part of my OGLUC class to answer request from dymanoid :

```
public partial class OGLUC : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Visual elements.
    private OGLViewer myoglviewer;               // OGL viewer that inherits from System::Windows::Forms::NativeWindow
    private swf.Panel winformsPanel;             // Windows Form Panel working as a container for OGL Viewer.
    private swfi.WindowsFormsHost winformsHost;  // A Windows Form to WPF host for the Panel.

    public OGLUC()
    {
       // OGL, Winform, WPF construction.
        winformsPanel = new swf.Panel();                             // Create the Winforms Panel control.
        winformsHost = new swfi.WindowsFormsHost();                  // Create the interop host control.
        winformsHost.Child = winformsPanel;
        myoglviewer = new OGLViewer(winformsPanel, 0, 0, winformsPanel.ClientSize.Width, winformsPanel.ClientSize.Height);          

        winformsPanel.SizeChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            //...
        };

        // Initialize this component.
        InitializeComponent();

        // Add the interop host control to this control's childrens.
        this.AddChild(winformsHost);
    }       
}
```

Comment: _"integrates a WinForms C++/CLI class that display an OpenGL window but I don't think that is important"_ Why do think that? I actually think this is crutial - but I am not familiar with using OpenGL in WPF. So I only can suggest to question that assumption.

Comment: You're right : mb this configuration make the rendering more difficult. What I actually mean is : the fact that it redraws correctly if I move my mouse over it make me think I can make it work without changing the C++ code .

Comment: I added the opengl tag because I think this is an important part here. Myself I can't be of more help, I am afraid. But this is really interesting for me, so I hope this helps to attract more "relevant" views to this q.

Comment: Please show us the details of how you integrate your WinForms component in the WPF realm. `WindowsFormsHost`? `ComponentDispatcher`? etc

Comment: I edit my question to answer your request

Comment: What is not clear to me: What causes the GL-view to redraw? Is it the event that the mouse moves over the GL-view? Is the GL-view focused (in which case `myoglviewer.Focus()` might help)? Is it the C++ code listening for mouse moved events which triggers the redraw? Is the GL-view only refreshing on mouse events or maybe also on keyboard events?